# Set hotmail account in Unity Mail

Tags: mail

I've been googling for quite some time but nowhere have I found a way to set a hotmail (windows live) account for Unity Mail. In preferences, under server data, I don't know what to put in the host / port fields.

Is Hotmail supported by Unity Mail anyway?

Comment: What is "Unity Mail" exactly?

Comment: [It's an application for Unity to display the unread email count on the Unity launcher as well as new mail notifications using NotifyOSD.](https://launchpad.net/unity-mail)

Comment: Close voters: Why would this be off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

No, Unity mail doesn't support POP3 only IMAP4 and Hotmail doesn't support IMAP4.

> The application works with any IMAP4-compatible server, but the quicklists currently work with Gmail only (so you'll have to edit the launcher if you want quicklists for a different mail service).

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/unity-mail-displays-gmail-unread-count.html).

And from the [Launchpad project page](https://launchpad.net/unity-mail):

Mail count and notifications for Ubuntu desktop

Features:

- **Works with any IMAP4-compatible server**
- Multiple accounts support
- Unread messages count on the Launcher
- Unity Quicklist support (GMail URLs by default)
- Messaging Menu integration
- NotifyOSD notifications

Comment: Can you update this answer. I think hotmail.com does allow for IMAP4 now.